# Java JSON streaming, non-blocking parser with POJO binding

Tags: java, json, jackson, reactive-programming

So there's actson that allows non-blocking JSON parsing. Then there's Jackson, that can't do non-blocking but can do POJO binding (databind). Is there a library that binds these two together? The main goal is to be able to feed byte arrays into the parser (no multithreading) and get a POJO in return, and then to be able to serialize that POJO back into JSON. With no intermediate JsonNode trees in both cases.

Comment: How would it suppose to work?

Comment: @Antoniossss as it would with a tree, just without one. It's perfectly possible, just needs to be implemented. Jackson guys are in the process of implementing it but I'm not sure it's ready yet.

Comment: Im just saying that I dont understand what do you want to achieve.

Comment: @Antoniossss Populating POJOs with data from JSON. In a streaming, non-blocking way. Streaming means it shouldn't expect full input JSON available immediately in-memory but should use pieces of input JSON without ever accumulating full input. Non-blocking means it shouldn't block on an input source, like an InputStream, to wait for more data, instead byte arrays are sometimes manually fed into the parser, at programmer's convenience, without multithreading.

Comment: @EJP the only way to implement push here is non-blocking reading of input, so I guess it's the same thing

Comment: It isn't the same thing, and it isn't the only way to implement push, unless there is something you haven't stated. Why do you think you need non-blocking?

Comment: @EJP To avoid growing threads as the number of incoming requests raises.

Answer (score 2):

For what it is worth, Jackson actually can now (with 2.9.0) do non-blocking parsing. API is similar to Aalto XML for XML, and I am guessing Actson as well.

Making POJO binding work does, however, require buffering of contents at this point (since feeding of input in non-blocking manner can not be yet done in this contexts): this can be done by using `TokenBuffer` helper class. Upcoming Spring 5 will likely contain functionality implemented this way.

Comment: Thanks for the info. For now I've rolled my own JSON to POJO deserialiser based on Actson without buffering.

Comment: Interesting. I assume this is for specific use case (that is, code for specific pojo types, and not something generic)? Buffering is definitely not mandatory in general, but not doing that requires some work on input handling that is non-obvious (at least for general case). However it is quite doable when code fully knows what to build.